# Syntax of if exists in IBM Db2

Tags: syntax, db2, if-statement

The follow query drops a table if the table exists but it doesnt seem to work for IBM Db2.

```
Begin atomic

if( exists(

SELECT 1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES 
            WHERE NAME='EMAIL' AND TYPE='T' AND creator = 'schema1'
)) then
drop table EMAIL;
end if;
End
```

Whereas the same if exists syntax works if i have a DML statement instead of table drop statement. Any help on this is appreciated

Update 1: I read that you cannot run DDL statement within begin atomic block hence my first statement fails but the second goes fine.

Comment: Are you getting an error message? If so, can you post that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way i did it is as follows

```
Begin atomic

  if( exists( SELECT 1 
              FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES 
              WHERE NAME='EMAIL' AND TYPE='T' AND creator = 'schema1' 
            )
    ) 
    then customStoredproc('drop table EMAIL'); 

  end if;

End
```

My customStoredProc just has one stmt execute immediate @dynsql;

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that DB2 prohibits DDL within an atomic SQL block. IBM has released a free add-on procedure called db2perf_quiet_drop that works the way you want.

Answer (score -3):

```
In case if you looking for embedded SQL:
Exec SQL                                   
  update Table1 set TabCol1 ='New Value' 
   where Table1KeyField1 =:Table1KeyValue1               
     and Table1KeyField2 =:Table1KeyValue2               
     and Exists (                          
       select '1' from Table2               
        where Table2KeyField1 =:Table2KeyValue1          
          and Table2KeyField2 =:Table2KeyValue2        
    ) ;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer to the OP question

Comment: The script is updating Table1 if record exists in Table2 based on where Clause. I embedded it in my RPG code and it worked. You may run below script and adjust your accordingly or send me you script and I'll fix it for you:                                  
  select '1' as true from SYSIBM/SYSDUMMY1
where exists(select * from  SYSIBM/SYSTYPINFO where type_name ='INTEGER');