# IBM DB2 INSERT when Count(*) = 0

Tags: sql, db2

Our development database gets reset weekly. I find myself spending an hour or so on Monday mornings (like today) inserting all of my test data into the various tables and databases from individual scripts.

First, of course, I have to verify that these tables do not have my data:

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM Table1 WHERE INVLINK LIKE '190701050630%'
```

If no rows are returned, I can insert my records:

```
INSERT INTO Table1
(       UPC,    CATALOG, VENDOR,  ADD_DATE, INVLINK, WHO_ADDED, TYPE, VENDOR_ID)
VALUES
('011010017760', 'LOVE', 'TES', '20150609', '19070105063041', 9388, 'P', '1013'),
('011010017760', 'HATE', 'TES', '20150609', '19070105063042', 9388, 'P', '1013'),
('011010017760', 'FEAR', 'TES', '20150609', '19070105063043', 9388, 'P', '1013')
```

What I would like to know is if there is a syntax that would allow me to call the insert command when the count is zero.

Here is what I've tried, **but this will not execute with an SQL call**.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SELECT Count(*) = 0
THEN 
INSERT INTO TBLBARTRANS
(       UPC,    CATALOG, VENDOR,  ADD_DATE, INVLINK, WHO_ADDED, TYPE, VENDOR_ID)
VALUES
('011010017760', 'LOVE', 'TES', '20150609', '19070105063041', 9388, 'P', '1013'),
('011010017760', 'HATE', 'TES', '20150609', '19070105063042', 9388, 'P', '1013'),
('011010017760', 'FEAR', 'TES', '20150609', '19070105063043', 9388, 'P', '1013')
END
FROM Table1 
WHERE INVLINK LIKE '190701050630%'
```

I can call the INSERT, SELECT, and UPDATE commands, but I am not a Database Administrator. So, creating a stored procedure to run these 15 to 20 scripts is not an option for me.

Comment: How about `if exists () then` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906554/syntax-of-if-exists-in-ibm-db2

Comment: ... why are you re-adding test data back yourself every week?  I feel like you (and your company) would benefit from an additional process or two...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - After developers have worked on (hacked/screwed up) the database for a week, it get pretty messed up. So, the DBAs are instructed to copy the live data over to the development database every weekend. Now, the code I am developing is to test multiple locations for products, which doesn't exist at the moment. Therefore, I have no data to test my code on. So, every week I have to reinsert it. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @jp2code - oh, I figured that's about what was happening.  What I'm getting at is, do something like have 1) Separate DEV environments with different refresh rates, or 2) A way to add (incoming) test data to the refresh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change that so that you only "select" those values that aren't there:

```
INSERT INTO TBLBARTRANS
 (UPC, CATALOG, VENDOR, ADD_DATE, INVLINK, WHO_ADDED, TYPE, VENDOR_ID)
select *
from (
  values 
    ('011010017760', 'LOVE', 'TES', '20150609', '19070105063041', 9388, 'P', '1013'),
   ('011010017760', 'HATE', 'TES', '20150609', '19070105063042', 9388, 'P', '1013'),
   ('011010017760', 'FEAR', 'TES', '20150609', '19070105063043', 9388, 'P', '1013')
) as t (UPC, CATALOG, VENDOR, ADD_DATE, INVLINK, WHO_ADDED, TYPE, VENDOR_ID)
where not exists (select 1 
                  from TBLBARTRANS tbl
                  where tbl.invlink = t.invlink);
```

The inner most select creates a "virtual" table that contains the values you want to insert:

```
select *
from (
  values 
    ('011010017760', 'LOVE', 'TES', '20150609', '19070105063041', 9388, 'P', '1013'),
    ('011010017760', 'HATE', 'TES', '20150609', '19070105063042', 9388, 'P', '1013'),
    ('011010017760', 'FEAR', 'TES', '20150609', '19070105063043', 9388, 'P', '1013')
) as t(UPC, CATALOG, VENDOR, ADD_DATE, INVLINK, WHO_ADDED, TYPE, VENDOR_ID)
```

the above simply "simulates" a source table for the values you want to insert. The condition

```
where not exists (select 1 
                  from TBLBARTRANS tbl
                  where tbl.invlink = t.invlink);
```

will then only return those rows from the "virtual" table that do not yet exist in the table `TBLBARTRANS`. The result of that select statement will then be inserted into the target table.

I tested this on a DB2 LUW - not sure if *all* DB2 versions support the `values()` clause as I have used it.

---

DB2's `MERGE` as suggested by Henrik is an alternative:

```
merge into TBLBARTRANS tg
using table (
  values 
    ('011010017760', 'LOVE', 'TES', '20150609', '19070105063041', 9388, 'P', '1013'),
    ('011010017760', 'HATE', 'TES', '20150609', '19070105063042', 9388, 'P', '1013'),
    ('011010017760', 'FEAR', 'TES', '20150609', '19070105063043', 9388, 'P', '1013')
) t (UPC, CATALOG, VENDOR,  ADD_DATE, INVLINK, WHO_ADDED, TYPE, VENDOR_ID) on (t.INVLINK = tg.invlink)
when not matched then 
  insert (UPC, CATALOG, VENDOR, ADD_DATE, INVLINK, WHO_ADDED, TYPE, VENDOR_ID)
  values (t.UPC, t.CATALOG, t.VENDOR, t.ADD_DATE, t.INVLINK, t.WHO_ADDED, t.TYPE, t.VENDOR_ID);
```

---

Unrelated, but:

Is `add_date` a `date` or `varchar` column? If it's a `varchar` column, then you should change that. Storing dates as strings is almost always a very bad idea.

The same is true for `VENDOR_ID`: you supply  string value to that column which looks very much like number. Storing numbers in varchar columns is also almost always a very bad idea.

Comment: `ADD_DATE` is stored as a char(8). Let me work on that answer of yours. It exceeds my SQL understanding. :)

Comment: @jp2code: run the `select` part on it's own to see what it's doing. Once you have that, it's just a standard `insert ... select...` solution.

Comment: The error this gives me is SQL0104N: Unexpected token "AS" was found following "8, 'P', '1013')) t". Expected tokens may include: "<space>".

Comment: Thanks for incorporating my suggestion of `MERGE` into your answer, so that we have a reference

Comment: The MERGE version you wrote works great! Our DB2 is v10.5.0.5, FixPack_num 5.

Comment: @jp2code: I had a typo in the SQL. It needs to be `..) as t (...` not `) t as (...`

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say which DB2 version and platform you are on, but most likely the `MERGE` statement may be what you are looking for. [MERGE is documented here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0010873.html).

You can specify your search conditions and insert/update depending on the outcome. And as with your requirements, you only need the privileges to insert, update, select...

Comment: +1. MERGE. A new word for me. It looks like, however, that it will not let me insert more than 1 record at a time. I get an error where the next line starts.

Comment: @jp2code: you can insert more than one row with `MERGE`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what others have said, you might consider moving your data to csv files and load/ingest those instead of inserting them inside an sql statement.

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0057198.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.1.0%2F3-6-2-4-59

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008305.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.1.0%2F3-6-2-4-83

Load will reject those rows that violates the primary key, and load the rest. Ingest gives you more control and you can even use a merge statement as described above.

Even if you don't want to use any of these utilities, you might want to consider keeping the data separate from the actual command. You could for example create a utility script that loops over a number of tables, reads that data file for the table and constructs the insert statement dynamically. All the information needed is in the catalog.

EDIT:

Yet another idea is to create backup tables that contain the data that you want to add to the real tables. I assume that by reset you mean that a backup is restored. If the backup contains the backup tables you can insert, merge, load from cursor from these tables every monday. Drawback is that you have to take a new backup when the data changes.

Comment: Interesting idea. If the CSV file is on my C drive and the IBM DB2 server is only accessible to the DBAs, will this technique work?

Comment: Not sure about ingest, for load you can do: `db2 load client from ...`. I'll extend my answer with yet another possibility.